# Convert decimal data to custom format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I have data in SQL Server with a data type of `decimal(19, 6)`.

When trying it convert to custom format I failed.

For example;

- The unformatted data: `1050.850000`
- I want to convert it to `1.050,00`

How can write this in T-SQL?

Comment: Conversion doesn't make any sense. How 1050.85 will be convert to 1.050

Comment: It seems from your example you want to FLOOR the number

Comment: What custom format? Decimals have no format. Formats apply when you convert the number to a string or when you parse a string to a number

Comment: Why do you remove the decimals when you want to display the final string *with* two decimals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimals, dates, integers etc have **no format**. They are all binary values. Formats apply only when you want to create a string from the value or parse a string to a value.

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function to format a decimal in a custom format, eg:

```
declare @data decimal(19,6)=1050.850000
select FORMAT(@data,'#,###.00')
```

The syntax of the format string is the same as .NET's

Your desired output truncates the decimals yet displays the value *with* decimals. In case this isn't a typo, you can either replace the decimals with literals, eg:

```
select FORMAT(@data,'#,###\.\0\0')
```

Or truncate the value before formatting

```
declare @data decimal(19,6)=1050.850000
select FORMAT(floor(@data),'#,###.00')
```

In previous SQL Server versions you are restricted to the predefined money type formats of the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function :

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar,cast(@data as money),1)
```

Note that `nvarchar` defaults to `nvarchar(30)`. Strings larger than 30 characters will be truncated to the first 30 characters.

Again, if you want to truncate the decimals, use the FLOOR function.

Comment: I work in SQL Server 2008, is there any function is available in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Just added this as well. You should be **really** be thinking about upgrading though as SQL Server 2008 mainstream (ie free patches) [ended in August 2014](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=sql). As a rule of thumb MS provides mainstream support for the last three versions of each product (including the current one)

Comment: Thanks Kanavos, I try to use CONVERT function and customize it.

Comment: My solution :select Replace( Replace(Replace(CONVERT(nvarchar,cast('1050.850000' as money),1)  ,',',' '),'.',','),' ','.')